# Wow64GetThreadContext bugged? (VB.NET)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi

Well I'm 99.9% certain I do everything correct. 
If I use Wow64GetThreadContext on x86 processes to receive the thread context it works perfectly, with all compile architecture types (x86, AnyCPU, x64)

If I try to retrieve the thread context from a thread on a x64 process it does not work. I know it shouldn't work with while calling from x86, but it doesn't even work getting called from x64 or AnyCPU(which is x64) to recieve the thread context of x64 process.
I get the error: Invalid Parameter.

When It's called in the code:

```
  Dim Context As New CONTEXT
  If IntPtr.Size = 8 Then
  Context.ConextFlags = &H10000 & &H2L
  Else
    Context.ConextFlags = &H10000L & &H2L
  End If
  If IntPtr.Size = 8 Then
      If Not Wow64GetThreadContext(PI.hThread, Context) Then Throw New Exception
  Else
      If Not GetThreadContext(PI.hThread, Context) Then Throw New Exception
  End If
```

Structures:

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Structure FLOATING_SAVE_AREA
    Dim Control, Status, Tag, ErrorO, ErrorS, DataO, DataS As UInteger
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=80)> Dim RegisterArea As Byte()
    Dim State As UInteger
End Structure
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Structure CONTEXT
    Dim ConextFlags, Dr0, Dr1, Dr2, Dr3, Dr6, Dr7 As UInteger, FloatSave As FLOATING_SAVE_AREA
    Dim SegGs, SegFs, SegEs, SegDs, Edi, Esi, Ebx, Edx, Ecx, Eax, Ebp, Eip, SegCs, EFlags, Esp, SegSs As UInteger
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=512)> Dim ExtendedRegisters As Byte()
End Structure
```

API Calls:

```
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, EntryPoint:="GetThreadContext"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()> _
Private Shared Function GetThreadContext( _
ByVal hThread As IntPtr, _
ByRef lpContext As CONTEXT) As Boolean
End Function
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, EntryPoint:="Wow64GetThreadContext"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()> _
Private Shared Function Wow64GetThreadContext( _
ByVal hThread As IntPtr, _
ByRef lpContext As CONTEXT) As Boolean
End Function
```

Comment: Why would you expect to call Wow64GetThreadContext for a non-WOW64 thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the bitness of the **calling process** to decide whether to use [`Wow64GetThreadContext()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681665.aspx) or [`GetThreadContext()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679362.aspx).  That is wrong.  `Wow64GetThreadContext()` can only be called by a 64bit process (it fails if called by a 32bit process), and it needs to be used only if the **target thread** is running in a 32bit process inside of the WOW64 emulator.

If the target thread is running inside of WOW64, use `Wow64GetThreadContext()` and [`WOW64_CONTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681670.aspx).  Use [`IsWow64Process()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139.aspx) to determine if the process that owns the target thread is running inside of WOW64 or not.

If the target thread is not running inside of WOW64, use `GetThreadContext()` and [`CONTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679284.aspx).  Do note, however, that the content of `CONTEXT` is highly dependant on the type of CPU used, so it will be different depending on whether it is called on a 32bit or 64bit thread, so you need to take that into account as well.

Try something more like this:

```
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Structure FLOATING_SAVE_AREA
    Dim Control, Status, Tag, ErrorO, ErrorS, DataO, DataS As UInteger
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=80)> Dim RegisterArea As Byte()
    Dim State As UInteger
End Structure

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)> _
Structure CONTEXT32
    Dim ContextFlags, Dr0, Dr1, Dr2, Dr3, Dr6, Dr7 As UInteger
    Dim FloatSave As FLOATING_SAVE_AREA
    Dim SegGs, SegFs, SegEs, SegDs, Edi, Esi, Ebx, Edx, Ecx, Eax, Ebp, Eip, SegCs, EFlags, Esp, SegSs As UInteger
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst:=512)> Dim ExtendedRegisters As Byte()
End Structure

' WOW64_CONTEXT is the same as CONTEXT32...

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=16)> _
Structure M128A
    Dim Low As ULong
    Dim High As Long
End Structure

<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=16)> _
Structure CONTEXT64
    Dim P1Home, P2Home, P3Home, P4Home, P5Home, P6Home As ULong
    Dim ContextFlags, MxCsr As UInteger
    Dim SegCs, SegDs, SegEs, SegFs, SegGs, SegSs As UShort
    Dim EFlags As UIneger
    Dim Dr0, Dr1, Dr2, Dr3, Dr6, Dr7, Rax, Rcx, Rdx, Rbx, Rsp, Rbp, Rsi, Rdi, R8, R9, R10, R11, R12, R13, R14, R15, Rip As ULong
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst:=2)> Dim Header As M128A()
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst:=8)> Dim Legacy As M128A()
    Dim Xmm0, Xmm1, Xmm2, Xmm3, Xmm4, Xmm5, Xmm6, Xmm7, Xmm8, Xmm9, Xmm10, Xmm11, Xmm12, Xmm13, Xmm14, Xmm15 As M128A
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeConst:=26)> Dim VectorRegister As M128A()
    Dim VectorControl, DebugControl, LastBranchToRip, LastBranchFromRip, LastExceptionToRip, LastExceptionFromRip As ULong
End Structure

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, EntryPoint:="GetThreadContext"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()> _
Private Shared Function GetThreadContext32( _
    ByVal hThread As IntPtr, _
    ByRef lpContext As CONTEXT32) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, EntryPoint:="GetThreadContext"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()> _
Private Shared Function GetThreadContext64( _
    ByVal hThread As IntPtr, _
    ByRef lpContext As CONTEXT64) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, EntryPoint:="Wow64GetThreadContext"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()> _
Private Shared Function Wow64GetThreadContext( _
    ByVal hThread As IntPtr, _
    ByRef lpContext As CONTEXT32) As Boolean
End Function

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError:=True, EntryPoint:="IsWow64Process"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity()> _
Private Shared Function IsWow64Process( _
    ByVal hProcess as IntPtr, _
    ByRef Wow64Process As Boolean) As Boolean
End Function
```

```
Dim IsWow64Proc As Boolean
If not IsWow64Process(PI.hProcess, IsWow64Proc) Then Throw New Exception

' If the target thread is running in WOW64 then query for CONTEXT32.
'
' Otherwise, if the calling process is 32-bit then it cannot access
' 64-bit threads so query for CONTEXT32 as well.
'
' Otherwise, this must be a 64-bit process querying a 64-bit thread
' so query for CONTEXT64...

If IsWow64Proc or IntPtr.Size = 4 Then
    Dim Context As New CONTEXT32
    Context.ContextFlags = &H10002L
    If IsWow64Proc Then
        If Not Wow64GetThreadContext(PI.hThread, Context) Then Throw New Exception
    Else
         If Not GetThreadContext32(PI.hThread, Context) Then Throw New Exception
    EndIf
    ...
Else
    Dim Context As New CONTEXT64
    Context.ContextFlags = &H100002L
    If Not GetThreadContext64(PI.hThread, Context) Then Throw New Exception
    ...
End If
```

Comment: Produces the same outcome, can not get the context on a 64bit process, produces this error: http://i.gyazo.com/d1978b26b92e8c3fa54a19dc1e13347d.png

Where do you get the CONTEXT64 Structure from? Haven't seen anything mentioned which looks like that
The WOW64_STRUCTURE as is you say same as the normal CONTEXT STRUCTURE.

I'm wondering because I need the Ebx, which isn't really mentioned there.

Comment: I don't use .NET myself, so I took a guess at how to marshal an array of structures. Obvious you will have to tweak the marshalling to make it work, but I hope you understand the jist of the answer even if the code is not 100% perfect.  As for the structure definitions, I got them from `winnt.h` in the Win32 API SDK, [as documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679284.aspx): "Refer to the header file WinNT.h for definitions of this structure for each processor architecture."  in x64, EBX is a subset of RBX.

Comment: In x64, [`EBX` is the lower 32 bits of `RBX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff561499.aspx).